# Will deleting the parent Github repository affect children forks?

Tags: github, repository, git-fork

I have a repository structure like this hosted on Github:

```
ParentRepo
|
-----ChildRepo
     |
     -----ChildOfChildRepo1
     |
     -----ChildOfChildRepo2
     |
     -----ChildOfChildRepo3
```

The `ChildRepo` is the "authoritative" repository, as far as where end users go for the latest code and to issue pull requests. This was forked from `ParentRepo`.

The `ChildOfChildRepoN` are forks made by end users, forked from the `ChildRepo`.

The `ParentRepo` is the parent of the `ChildRepo` authoritative repository fork. Occasionally I push commits from the `ChildRepo` fork up to the `ParentRepo`.

I control `ParentRepo` under one Github account, and `ChildRepo` under another Github account.

If I delete the `ParentRepo` repository, will that in any way affect `ChildRepo` and its child forks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the child forks only know about `ChildRepo`, and `ChildRepo` will still be around **if it is a public repo**.

See "[GitHub help: Deleting a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository)"

> **Deleting a private repository also deletes all of its forks**.
>   **Deleting a public repository will not**.

However, asking GitHub support for confirmation is a good idea.

That might affect any pending pull request from `ChildRepo` to `ParentRepo` though.

Comment: Here's the official answer, but unfortunately, the tree structure got screwed up, where a random child was made into a parent. Not sure if that's a bug, or by design: https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility#deleting-a-public-repository