# When I delete a repo on github, can I pick the new parent from the forks or is it randomly assigned?

Tags: github

When I delete a public repository on github that has public forks, I understand that one of the public forks will become the new parent.  I would like to specify which of the multiple forks should be the new parent, because one is the most advanced, while others are orphans.  But can I make this choice or is the parent randomly assigned?

The [Github Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#deleting-a-public-repository) seems a bit ambiguous to me: "When you delete a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository. All other repositories are forked off of this new parent and subsequent pull requests go to this new parent."

Comment: Does it make sense to transfer ownership of the repo?

Comment: @Daenyth, I don't think so in this case: the current parent (that I'd like to delete) was created by an employee in their own repository and then it was forked by the organization he worked for as well as several others.  The organization fork has had all the improvements while the parent is just the initial commit.

Comment: @VonC answered my question, but to solve my problem, I think I need to ask github support to detach the fork from the existing parent and turn it into a stand-along repo: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commit-was-made-in-a-fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One user tried it before in "[Will deleting the parent Github repository affect children forks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519508/6309)".

His comment was explicit:

> unfortunately, the tree structure got screwed up, where a random child was made into a parent.

So you don't get to pick which repo becomes the parent.