# What happens after repository deleting if it was mirrored?

Tags: git, github, mirror

I have a git repo (on Github) with a webhook in order to have a mirror repo (also on GitHub) always in sync.

If I delete the "source" repo, what happens to the mirrored repo? It will be saved or it will be deleted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will deleting the parent Github repository affect children forks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519508/will-deleting-the-parent-github-repository-affect-children-forks)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+delete+parent+repository

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but mirroring and forking are not equals...with mirroring you have a sync copy, with fork you take a photo in a time instant, do you agree?

Comment: A mirror might be a special case of a fork, but it is a fork nonetheless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I delete the "source" repo, what happens to the mirrored repo?

Nothing.  Every repository is independent of any other repository.

Of course, any attempt to run`git fetch origin` on the mirror will fail, but that means nothing happens in the mirror.